# Erlang, how can I create text file with newlines?

Tags: file, erlang, newline, writefile, erl

Somebody knows how can I append a **new line** in the text file in **Erlang** language?
I want to save this list:

```
Data = ["one", "two", "three"],
```

into the text file with new lines:

```
one
two
three
```

I tried:

```
write() ->
    Data = ["1","2","3"],
    Print = string:join(Data, "\n"),
    file:write_file("/Documents/foo.txt", [Print]).
```

But it creates a text file with inline data:

```
one\ntwo\nthree
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm guessing you're running your code on Windows, and so you need `"\r\n"` as the line separator. You can get the line separator appropriate for the platform you're on by calling `io_lib:nl/0`.

Try this instead:

```
write() ->
    Data = ["1","2","3"],
    LineSep = io_lib:nl(),
    Print = [string:join(Data, LineSep), LineSep],
    file:write_file("/Documents/foo.txt", Print).
```

Here, `Print` is an instance of *iodata*, which is either an `iolist` or a `binary`, where an `iolist` is an arbitrarily deep list consisting of one or more characters, binaries, or other iolists. It's an extremely handy data type for output in Erlang because it means you can avoid having to flatten your data before writing it to a file or sending it over a socket. This version of the `write` function uses the `iodata` form for the `Print` variable to easily ensure that the final line of data written to the file is followed by a line separator, something that `string:join/2` by itself won't do.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
write() ->
    Data = ["1","2","3"],
    Print = string:join(Data, "\n"),
    file:write_file("/Documents/foo.txt", Print).
```

Comment: The result of this code will be identical to that of the original poster.